# How to solve the limit of a multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the following limit, when I try to approach it on the x-axis the result is 0, and when I try to approach it on the y-axis the result is 0, I can therefore not say if it exists or not.

lim                 (x-4)<sup>3</sup>  (y-1)<sup>5</sup> 
(x, y) → (4, 1)     __________
                             (x-4)<sup>8</sup> + (y-1)<sup>8</sup>

switching to polar cordinates: 
x = r cost + 4
y = r cost + 1

          lim                 ((r cost + 4) - 4)<sup>3</sup>  ((r sin t + 1)-1)<sup>5</sup> 
       r → 0            ________________________
                             ((r cost + 4) - 4)<sup>8</sup> + ((r sin t + 1) - 1)<sup>8</sup>

lim                 (r cost)<sup>3</sup>  (r sin t)<sup>5</sup> 
       r → 0            ______________
                             (r cost)<sup>8</sup> + (r sin t)<sup>8</sup>

lim                 r<sup>3</sup> cos<sup>3</sup>t  r<sup>5</sup> sin <sup>5</sup>t 
       r → 0            ______________
                             (r<sup>8</sup> cos<sup>8</sup>t) + (r<sup>8</sup> sin<sup>8</sup>t)

lim                 r<sup>8</sup> cos<sup>3</sup>t  sin <sup>5</sup>t 
       r → 0            ______________
                              r<sup>8</sup>((cos<sup>8</sup>t) + (sin<sup>8</sup>t))

lim                 cos<sup>3</sup>t   sin <sup>5</sup>t 
       r → 0            ______________
                              ((cos<sup>8</sup>t) + (sin<sup>8</sup>t))

In the last part, I no longer have **r** in my expression left. Does this mean that the limit does not exist?

Comment: Although it is an impressive feat to have gotten the expression readable without MathJax, please check the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks André, I will check it out:)

Comment: Are you familiar with using polar coordinates? as in  setting $x=r \cos(\theta)+4$ and $y=r \sin(\theta)+1$? and then letting $r\to 0$

Comment: yes, but since (x,y) → (4,1), can I really say that r → 0 then ? :)

Comment: Notice that $x = r\cos(\theta)+4$ approaches $4$ as $r\to 0$ and similarly for $y$.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will try it out:) thank you André

Comment: I get an answer where r → 0, but there is no longer an r in my expression left, does that mean that the limit doesn't exist? @AndréArmatowski

Comment: I added my response to your last question as an answer :)

Comment: You will find this useful: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the post we switched the limit to a limit with polar coordinates using $$x=r\cos(\theta)+4 \quad \text{and} \quad y=r\sin(\theta)+1$$
then as $r\to 0$ we have $x\to 4$ and $y \to 1$.

This new limit is then
\begin{align*}\lim_{(x,y)\to (4,1)}\frac{(x-4)^{3}(y-1)^{5}}{(x-4)^{8}+(y-1)^{8}} &= \lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^{8}\cos^{3}(\theta)\sin^{5}(\theta)}{r^{8}\cos^{8}(\theta)+r^{8}\sin^{8}(\theta)}\\
&=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{\cos^{3}(\theta)\sin^{5}(\theta)}{\cos^{8}(\theta)+\sin^{8}(\theta)}\\
&=\frac{\cos^{3}(\theta)\sin^{5}(\theta)}{\cos^{8}(\theta)+\sin^{8}(\theta)}.
\end{align*}

Here we can see that we will get the limit to be $0$ if we approach either along the $y- axis$ or $x-axis$ (that is when $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2},0 \ \text{or} \ \pi$). However, pick any theta such that both $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ are not $0$ and you will get a nonzero limit. Therefore the limit does not exist.

Note: This is the answer to the question before it was edited to say something else.

Comment: Wow thank you so much:)

Comment: There is a typo for $(y-1)^4$.

Comment: @user Thanks for pointing it out! Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

By $u=x-4\to 0$ and $v=y-1\to 0$ we have

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (4,1)}\frac{(x-4)^{3}(y-1)^{5}}{(x-4)^{8}+(y-1)^{8}}=\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)}\frac{u^{3}v^{5}}{u^{8}+v^{8}}$$

and by $v=u\to 0$

$$\frac{u^{3}v^{5}}{u^{8}+v^{8}}=\frac{u^{3}u^{5}}{u^{8}+u^{8}}=\frac{u^{8}}{2u^{8}}=\frac12 \to \frac12$$

while by $v=-u\to 0$

$$\frac{u^{3}v^{5}}{u^{8}+v^{8}}=\frac{-u^{3}u^{5}}{u^{8}+u^{8}}=-\frac{u^{8}}{2u^{8}}=-\frac12 \to -\frac12$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.